# Clickable link gives nothing as output

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I wanted to ask ppl after they used the programm if they want to join the Discord y/n if they answer with y it should give out a clickable link but if i do it is just saying `None` This is the Whole output:

```
      ====================================================
      ==                 Keygenerator                   ==
      ====================================================
    
How many serial codes are you looking for? 
1
Do you want to join our Discord Server y/ny
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Heres the Code:

```
print("""
      ====================================================
      ==                 Keygenerator                   ==
      ====================================================
    """)

status = ""
import webbrowser
import random,sys

def Discord():
    webbrowser.open(Discord Invite link)

def Mainmenu():
    input("Do you want to join our Discord Server y/n")
    if status == "y":
        print(Discord())

def main():
    seq = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

    count = int(input("How many serial codes are you looking for? \n"))
    with open("demofile2.txt.", 'w') as text_file:
        for _ in range(count):
            print('-'.join(''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in range(5)) for _ in range(5)), file=text_file)
            # text_file.write('-'.join(''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in range(5)) for _ in range(5)) + '\n')

        print("\nCreated {} serial keys.".format(count), file=text_file)
        # text_file.write("\nCreated {} serial keys.\n".format(count))

        print(Mainmenu())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also tried it instead with:

```
def Discord():
    print("Works?")
```

Would be great if you could explain me why i get None as Output

Comment: Your function discord doesn't return anything, so `print` displays None

Comment: How do you mean that? Im very new to python

Comment: I don't know much about discord, but please tell me what do you expect `print(Discord())` to display

Comment: it should print my link and the link should be clickable